# can't get image url with camera.getPicture phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i'm trying to pick an image from gallery and alert with the image url,
the gallery is opened but no alerts shown on mobile with android 4.1.2 but run correctly on mobile with android 2.3.6 !!!
my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function getImage() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFailure, {
                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                });


                function onSuccess(imageURI) {
                    img_uri = imageURI;
                    alert(img_uri);

                }


                function onFailure(message) {
                    alert("Get image failed: " + message);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the logcat in eclipse, after selected image from gallery, if your app start again from onCreate, it said that you app activity had kill, you can get the selected image uri from onActivityResult.

Comment: how can i get the selected image uri from onActivityResult in phonegap ??